# Import Latest csv file in a folder - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, etl

I want to import the latest csv file into a table using SSIS? I currently have a step that gets the last file in a folder:

```
 Report_201209030655.csv
 Report_201209030655.csv
 Report_201209030655.csv
```

Based on created time I want steps to import data of the latest csv to a table.

Comment: Can`t you just move older/already processed files to separate folder? I believe it's the most common approach in ETL.

Comment: Before this step I am actually renaming and moving the file to a new folder

Answer (score 0):

refer this solution:

```
[http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/][1]
```

then use script task to populate the file name and pass that variable as file name for source component.

Getting latest file code:

```
   public void Main()
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\SSIS\Files");
            DataTable NewList=new DataTable();
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("FileName");
            NewList.Columns.Add(col);

            System.IO.FileInfo finf;
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                finf = new System.IO.FileInfo(f);
                if (finf.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24))
                {
                    NewList.Rows.Add(f);
                }
            }
            Dts.Variables["User::FileNameArray"].Value = NewList;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Yes but in the flat file source step mentioned by Pinal....we are to specify the file name.In the case I have specified the file name will change every minute.Also where do I use the Script Component?

Comment: before flat file source add Script task and then add the code to get latest file name and assign that to a variable and use that variable in flat file source

Comment: use the script task in dataflow task

Comment: When the script component is tried to connect to flat file source step I get could not connect connector error.
Also the script when pasted gives error...Syntax error

Comment: I guess you have to use script task in control flow

Comment: [OLE DB Destination [9]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Native Client"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".  the OLE DB Connection step is throwing this error

Comment: Looks like your DB connection to sql server is not proper.Create proper destination connection